# Remove space from vertical and horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x15c.jpg)

Remove box space from vertical and horizontal scroll bar

Comment: can you insert your code?

Comment: sorry i can not share code https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x15c.jpg

Comment: sorry without that we can't able to help you.

Comment: never mind... Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible because scroll is a native ui. However it is obviously possible if you make your own scrollbar using JS.

This is the closest that I can get with CSS

```css
.case-1 .wrapper{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto; 
}
.case-1 .wrapper .something{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
.case-2 .wrapper{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.case-2 .wrapper-inner{
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.case-2 .wrapper .wrapper-inner .something{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.case{
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-1 case">
  <h4>Normal</h4>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="something"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-2 case">
  <h4>Desired</h4>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
      <div class="something"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the property [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp).
The `overflow-x` property controls whether the content of the block element is displayed horizontally and `overflow-y` vertically.